# Because of COVID-19 is the Thailand visa on arrival cancelled for all the countries?

Tags: visas, thailand, event-based-effects, visas-on-arrival, covid-19

I read in a [recent article](https://www.thestar.com.my/news/regional/2020/03/11/thailand-suspends-visa-on-arrival-for-18-countries)

> BANGKOK (The Nation/ANN): The government has decided to suspend visa
>   on arrival for visitors from 18 countries at a meeting on Wednesday
>   (March 11), chaired by Prime Minister Prayut Chan-o-cha, also head of
>   the Covid-19 management centre.

However, I read in a [more recent article](https://www.straitstimes.com/asia/se-asia/coronavirus-thailand-puts-visa-on-arrival-visa-free-entry-cancellation-on-hold)

> BANGKOK (THE NATION/ASIA NEWS NETWORK) - The government has put on
>   hold its plan to suspend visa on arrival (VoA) for 18 countries and
>   visa-free entry from high-risk areas (South Korea, Hong Kong and
>   Italy) after an urgent meeting on Thursday (March 12).

I am an Indian traveler and want to know whether visa on arrival is still valid or canceled.  Does anyone here have recent experience?

Answer (score 4):

This is the latest information in the IATA website:

“ 7. Nationals of Bulgaria, Bhutan, China (People's Rep.), Cyprus, Ethiopia, Fiji, Georgia, India, Kazakhstan, Malta, Mexico, Nauru, Papua New Guinea, Romania, Saudi Arabia, Uzbekistan, Vanuatu and passengers with a Chinese Taipei (on the cover: Republic of China Taiwan) passport can no longer obtain a visa on arrival.”

The update was published today https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm Check back for further updates